# How to force openEJB to ignore mappedName and use openejb.jndiname.format instead

Tags: openejb

I have an EJB:

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "MetadataFacade")
public class MetadataFacade implements MetadataFacadeRemote {
```

and openEJB configured using:

```
-Dopenejb.jndiname.format={ejbClass.simpleName}#{interfaceClass}
```

When embedded openEJB is starting it ignores the openejb.jndiname.format option and creates incorrect JNDI name:

```
INFO   info, Jndi(name=MetadataFacade) --> Ejb(deployment-id=MetadataFacade)
```

How can I configure it to use the openejb.jndiname.format option and create JNDI name similar to:

```
MetadataFacade#my.package.MetadataFacadeRemote
```

?

If openEJB can not do it, I would be thankful for any workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the described use case is not supported, I have created a patch

[mappedName.patch](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BwaHPvQj1ETVYzliYWRiN2MtYjI3NS00Mjc0LWE0MDgtZjdlMzE0MjMyM2I3&hl=en_US)

which disables the original behaviour and instead adds a new variable **ejbClass.mappedName** which can be used in **openejb.jndiname.format**.

---

The patch is for the head (revision 1034599) of:

```
 http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/openejb/tags/openejb-3.1.4
```

Apply it to sources root using:

```
patch -p0 -i mappedName.patch
```

then build openEJB using:

```
mvn -Dmaven.{test,itest}.skip -Dassemble clean install
```

and add

[container/openejb-core/target/openejb-core-3.1.4.jar](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BwaHPvQj1ETVZmVlY2YwMzAtZGYwZS00OGM0LWFmMTMtOTA4NDIzNDIyNWQ3)

to your classpath as the first entry.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing for that now, but we can probably add a flag to configure this.  What version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, a flag would be great. It would allow me to precisely match the Weblogic jndi name format for my project. I use Apache OpenEJB 3.1.4    build: 20101112-03:32.

Comment: I am trying to get the same behaviour that mmm. Do you know if it's patch was integrated into the application ?

Comment: I do not know for sure, but I did not submitted it.